# VBscript HTTP Status msgbox only pops up once issue

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, hta, httpapplication

Here is the VBscript code inside a MS-HTA i am making, It's supposed to check for updates against a webserver every run.

But it isn't working, It does pop up once then if the user hits ok and doesn't 
 download the new version, even if they remain on old version it never prompts again.

Any way i can make it prompt every run if the version is still outdated?
Needs to be VBScript that can work inside a HTMLApplication MS-HTA.

```
Dim varHTTP, varBinaryString, varFileName, varLink

set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set varHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Set varBinaryString = CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")

varFileName = "YoutubeDLV2.zip"
varNewFileName = "YoutubeDLV3.zip"
varLink = "https://MyURL.com/YTDL/V2/" & varFileName
varNewLink = "https://MyURL.com/YTDL/V3/" & varNewFileName
varHTTP.Open "GET", varLink, False
varHTTP.Send

CheckFile()

Sub CheckFile()
Select Case Cint(varHTTP.status)
    Case 200, 202, 302 
        'it exists
        Exit Sub
    Case Else
        'does not exist         
        msgbox "Update Found! Go to:" & vbNewLine & 
"https://MyURL.com/YTDL/" & vbNewLine & "And download latest version." & 
vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Currently Running Version." & vbNewLine + varLink & 
vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Newest Version:" & vbNewLine + varNewLink
End Select
End Sub
```

Seems to be this line causing issues

```
Case 200, 202, 302
```

Case 202 - Causes prompt every time by its self

Case 200, 202, 302 - causes it only once even if declined

Case 200 - does nothing by its self

```
200 – OK (standard successful http request)
202 – Accepted (request accepted for processing, but not completed)
302 – Found (via redirection)
```

As i said above, This code does work but only once. I would like it to work every time, I'm at a loss as to why i cant get it to work, Any ideas?

--- EDIT

I just went with batch as i know it better, and made this that works. it does depend on version 5 of powershell so wont work in windows 7, and a third party wget standalone exe but it works :)

```
:main
cls
set version=2.0
set filename=YoutubeDLV3.zip
wget.exe --no-check-certificate https://mysite/YTDL/version.txt >nul
set /p nwstvrsn=<version.txt
set nwstvrsn=%nwstvrsn: =%
if %version% lss %nwstvrsn% goto newupdateavailable
if %version%==%nwstvrsn% goto noupdateavailable
goto main


:newupdateavailable
cls
echo.
echo Downloading Update...
echo.
wget.exe --no-check-certificate https://mysite/YTDL/V2/%filename% -O "%filename%"
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
PowerShell.exe Expand-Archive %filename% -DestinationPath %userprofile%\Downloads\
pause
exit

:noupdateavailable
cls
echo.
echo No Update Available
echo.
pause
exit
```

and telling it to run from the hta with

```
Sub  Window_onload

Const NORMAL_WINDOW = 1
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute "VersionCheck.bat", "", , , NORMAL_WINDOW

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not set it to Case 404 and swap the logic?

Comment: 404 doesnt seem to work, no prompt either way, guessing since my site provides a 404 error page with a file path not like a redirect to site.com/404/, on no file its counting that as still valid. when showing the 404 in place of like mysite.com/YoutubeDLV2.zip

Comment: @NathanRice Logic of that was solid but doesnt seem to work for me. :(

Comment: Can you update with more detail? Why exactly did that not work?

Comment: `varHTTP.status` is going to update every time you make the request, right? So how will it get updated if you're only calling `CheckFile()` (and `varHTTP.Send` is out of this method)?

Comment: @NathanRice, i do say what works, with my above post it displays the update prompt once when ran as it should but issue is never again even if not updated. running again causes no prompt, and the case 404 causes no output.

Comment: CheckFiles is my function in the Sub that is called, so calling that should trigger the varHTTP.status to do the actual check, and does work just only once. i need it to run on every startup of app unless user updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just went with batch as i know it better, and made this that works. it does depend on version 5 of powershell so wont work in windows 7, and a third party wget standalone exe but it works :)

```
:main
cls
set version=2.0
set filename=YoutubeDLV3.zip
wget.exe --no-check-certificate https://mysite/YTDL/version.txt >nul
set /p nwstvrsn=<version.txt
set nwstvrsn=%nwstvrsn: =%
if %version% lss %nwstvrsn% goto newupdateavailable
if %version%==%nwstvrsn% goto noupdateavailable
goto main


:newupdateavailable
cls
echo.
echo Downloading Update...
echo.
wget.exe --no-check-certificate https://mysite/YTDL/V2/%filename% -O "%filename%"
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
PowerShell.exe Expand-Archive %filename% -DestinationPath %userprofile%\Downloads\
pause
exit

:noupdateavailable
cls
echo.
echo No Update Available
echo.
pause
exit
```

and telling it to run from the hta with

```
Sub  Window_onload

Const NORMAL_WINDOW = 1
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute "VersionCheck.bat", "", , , NORMAL_WINDOW

End Sub
```